# create new collection from filter query without duplicate id using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am creating new collection from existing one.
In this code, keywords will be stored into a list from file.

```
        BufferedReader keyword = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Leave.txt"));

        String str;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((str = keyword.readLine()) != null)
        {
            list.add(str);
        }

        String[] psentiments = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Here, I am checking with my collection weather any of status has the specific word. if it finds then it will insert into the new collection. It works quite well but if it compares with same status for different keyword, it throws me an error. 
   Insert code:

```
            MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection1.find().iterator();
           try {
               while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                   Document dr = cursor.next();
                   String stat =  dr.getString("status");
                    for(String i:psentiments){
                        if(stat.contains(i)){
                            //System.out.println( stat+"-->"+i+ counter);
                            createcollection(dr,collection1, new ObjectId(dr.get("_id").toString()),newcoll);
                            counter++;
                        }

                    }
               }

           } finally {
               cursor.close();
           }
}

private static void createcollection(Document dr, MongoCollection<Document> collection1, ObjectId objectId, MongoCollection<Document> newcoll) {
```

//I need help here.. insert document without duplicate

```
    newcoll.insertOne(dr);


}
```

Result:

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Brexit.Leave index: *id* dup key: { : ObjectId('573334f5fbfb8711f0c7ac44') }
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:523)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:306)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:297)
    at twitter.sample.createcollection(sample.java:66)
    at twitter.sample.main(sample.java:52)

The last two status has same key. I don't know how to insert without duplication and also only one status should be inserted.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use save() method.

> save() - Update an existing document or insert a document depending on the parameter.